# I need to add a JavaScript load function that loads once

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, lightbox

I am searching for a way to add a function that tells my `.playerWindow` to only load once using cookies. Right now it loads every time I refresh the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $("#button").click(function () {
            $("#overlay").fadeTo(1000, .8);
            $(".playerWindow").show(750);
            //$("body").scrollTop(0);
        });

        $(".closePlayer, #overlay").click(function () {
            $(".playerWindow").hide(750);
            $("#overlay").fadeOut(1000);
        });

    });

    $(window).load(function () {
        if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') === -1) {
            var fifteenDays = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 15;
            var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
            document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
            $("#overlay").fadeTo(1000, .8);
            $(".playerWindow").show(750);
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: *$(this)... is.... JAVAAAAASCRIPT*

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).load(function() {
  if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') === -1) {
    var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
    var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
    document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
    $("#overlay").fadeTo(1000, .8);
    $(".playerWindow").show(750);
  }
});
```

To clarify, this HTML page works for me on my Apache server.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(window).load(function() {
           if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') === -1) {
              var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
              var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
              document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
              alert("bam!");
         }
    });


         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It displays "bam!" the first time I visit, and then nothing the second, third, etc.  Opening an Incognito Window in Chrome causes it to appear again.

Comment: Try it out.  If there aren't any problems with the rest of your code, it should work.

Comment: can you review my code above. I added the code you provided. When I tested the code on a page it still pops up every time i refresh the page.  preview page [link](http://secure984.hostgator.com/~shoprdr/TESTING/hover/hoverTEST.html)